# C Fast Median Filter on Rosetta Stone (C I/O and images)

Tags: c, image, filter, io, median

So, I'm playing around with image processing and I happen to stumble on [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Median_filter) C implementation of a Median Filter. Because there isn't much in the way of comments or documentation I compiled this code on my Linux machine and started running GDB to start seeing what it does. As input parameters I put in (filter window size, input image, output image)...

```
5  image.txt  ouput.jpg
```

I also tried...

```
5  image.jpg  ouput.jpg
```

and absolute addresses...

The image.txt/image.jpg is in the same directory as the compiled code. Running line by line I successfully reach this...

```
if (fgetc(fp) != 'P' || fgetc(fp) != '6' || !isspace(fgetc(fp)))
    goto bail;
```

which in turn takes me here.

```
bail:
if (fp) fclose(fp);
return im;
```

After which I'll get segmentation fault inside of median_filter(in, size) because in is 0.

Can someone explain why the program chooses to 'bail' whenever it doesn't see these chars in the file stream. More so what format is expecting as input? My suspension is that these two questions maybe linked.

Thanks!

Comment: okay, so instead of downvoting can you actually explain what you don't like about the question?

Comment: <le sigh> I swear some of the more pretentious members of this community need a reality check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is checking if the first character is 'P' and second is '6'. So the magic number for this image format is 'P6'.

This corresponds to [**PPM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) format.

Input image should be of PPM format

Comment: Thank you! I was guessing initially that ppm_in was indicating file format but when I searched in Google I got links related to the measurement not the format :) . I still don't understand why this got down voted was this super obvious or something?